# eBay iFrame listing autoheight

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I was looking at creating my own ebay listing templates when I thought of using iframes the only trouble is Cross Site Scripting.

This is on ebay

```
// this script gets the height of the iframe which is stored in a hidden field on the iframe

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var input = innerDoc.getElementById('size').value;
    document.getElementById('iframeId').style.height = input;
}

var ax="ifr";
var bx="ame src='htt";
var cx="p://";
var link="mywebsite.com/Ebay?page=";
var page = "iframeTest"
document.write("<"+ax+bx+cx+link+page);
document.write("'id='iframeId' onload='resizeIframe(this)' width='98%' scrolling='no' frameBorder='0'>"+"</ifr"+"ame>");
-->;
</script>
```

This is the iframe

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1><center>Ebay Test Listing</center></h1>
    <input type="text" id="size">
            other information etc...
    </div>
</body>
<script>
var aheight =  document.getElementById('wrapper').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("size").value = aheight;
</script>
```

Now the iframe is on my website but how can I send the height of the iframe to mywebsite and adjust it automatically?

The script works perfectly when running the ebay code on my site?

Answer (score -1):

You can't. This is not possible.